# How to export a struct to a file, and then memory map the file?

Tags: c++, struct, mmap, memory-mapped-files, memory-mapping

I have a struct that I'd like to export to a file, and then mmap() that file. One issue is that the struct has a member variable that is a string, and I'm not sure how mmap would handle that. In this case all of these strings are of identical size, 8 characters. I'm working on Windows, although I'm using an [mmap()](http://www.minasgjoka.com/classprojects/uncompressed/netflix-project/src/winmmap.cpp) function I found online which is supposed to replicate the Linux mmap() function.

The struct itself is defined as:

```
struct testStruct
{
    string testString;
    unsigned int testInt;
    unsigned int tsetArr[9];
};
```

Is it possible to define the return value of sizeof() for an object?

Would mmapping a file which contains struct data be possible?

What code would I have to use to export the struct to a file, and then mmap it?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The representation of `std::string` is not guaranteed by the C++ standard, so this won't work. `std::string` may (and commonly will) allocate its contents anywhere on the heap, so you'll be storing a pointer and a size member, rather than the string itself.

A `char` array with compile-time constant size, such as `tsetArr`, should work, though.

> Is it possible to define the return value of sizeof() for an object?

No. `sizeof` is not a function, so you can't overload it (and strictly, it has a *value*, but not a *return value* since it doesn't *return* from anywhere; it's expanded to a constant by the compiler).

> Would mmapping a file which contains `struct` data be possible?

Possible, yes, but I advise against it; your code will not be portable, perhaps not even to different compilers on the same platform, and your `struct` is cast in stone. If you want to do so anyway, only `mmap` POD (plain old data) with no pointer members and put an `unsigned version` member in your `struct` that you increment every time its definition is changed.

Comment: Thanks. Would it be possible to memory map a vector of strings then, assuming all strings have the same number of characters (8)?

Comment: @Tristan: `std::vector` has the same problem as `std::string`: it allocates its contents on the heap (and may change the location if necessary for growth). A 2-d array (`char[N][8]` for some compile-time constant `N`) should work.

Comment: Thanks again. After I read the mmap the file of 8 character strings to the 2-d array, what would be the fastest way to then access each of those N items as a string? I will be dealing with hundreds of thousands of items so speed is important.

Comment: You mean as an `std::string`? Don't; you'd have to do hundreds of thousands of constructions, each involving a memory allocation. Use them as `char*` instead.

Comment: I'm a bit confused. Can you give an example of the declaration of this array that would be mapped? And how do you mmap to a 2-d array?

Comment: Set of `N` strings, each of length 8 + NUL: `char str[N][9]`. You'd put that in a `struct`, then `mmap` as you would ordinarily.

Comment: Thankyou, larsmans, for bringing some semblance of sanity into this question. +1 from me.

Comment: Thank you larsman, but I'm not sure how to mmap ordinarily here since it's a 2-d array and that's confusing me. For instance I'd think to mmap like:
`char *fileMap = (char*) mmap(...);` But that would be 1-dimensional. How does one call the 2-d mmap? Also, I assume the NULL is to terminate the char string, but how is that used in code?

Comment: @Tristan: this is very hard to answer without seeing an attempt at `mmap`'ing, which would warrant a new question. However, a 2-d array in C is just a 1-d array in disguise. (And please don't cast the result from `mmap`; it's `void*`, so it will be converted automatically. Casting it only hides potential bugs.)

Answer (score 1):

```
struct testStruct
{
    char testString[9];
    unsigned int testInt;
    unsigned int tsetArr[9];
};
```